# One database at MongoDB is not responding

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have several databases under the mongodb instance (v 4.0.26) in a Ubuntu 18.04 server.
One of the database has started behaving inconsistently in terms of connectivity all of a sudden.
I have checked the resource consumption on the server. 7GB of RAM left and 34GB of storage also available.
In Mongo Shell (at the server), when I connect to the particular database and perform `db.getCollectionNames()` it just hangs. This behavior is also not consistent. But every other database in that instance works without any problem.

I am suspecting there could be a corrupt document in any of the collection which is resulting this. Looking for guidance to debug this issue.

P.S.: Losing the data in db might cost my job.

Comment: P. S. Do you have a backup?

Comment: Did you have a look at the log file?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes. I do have a back up. Yes. I could not find anything different/wrong in logs.

Comment: I would suggest to create a new mongo instance and copy all data with `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. Then you would be on the safe side.